# GCP patch compliance data of VM Instances - get/list API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, gcloud

How to get the details in the below dashboard (whether the VM Instances are compliance or not).

Steps to reach in console:

- Login to google cloud platform
- Navigate to **os patch management**
- Navigate to **vm instances** tab

[image: Retrieve the dashboard data in this image=]

Already tried the APIs [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/os-patch-management/manage-patch-jobs#list-instance-details), but it only returns Patch Job specific data, not vm instance specific details.

Comment: If you monitor the network tab in the browser's developer tools, you may be able to determine which API is being called. In (increasingly rare) cases, Google uses private APIs for Console functionality

Comment: Alternatively, if there's a ,`gcloud` command with equivalent functionality, you can append `--log-http` to see what underlying calls it's making

Answer (score 0):

You can follow examples provided in the [compliance reports documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/os-configuration-management/view-compliance#view_compliance_state):

> To view detailed compliance state for a specific VM, create a GET request to the projects.locations.instanceOSPoliciesCompliances.get method.

```
GET https://osconfig.googleapis.com/v1alpha/projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/ZONE/instanceOSPoliciesCompliances/INSTANCE
```

Comment: Thank you.. You have given the result of VM instances tab on the OS configuration management page. But I'm expecting OS Patch Management console, VM Instance tab related data.. Is there a connection between these two? The difference is OS Policy complaice and OS Patch Compliance as I think!

Comment: Did you try the following API from this [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/os-patch-management/manage-patch-jobs)
`https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/os-patch-management/manage-patch-jobs`

Comment: Tried this, but it doesn't contain the details of whether an instance is compliant or not. The information has to be retrieved instance-wise, not patch jobwise..

Comment: @RajeevTirumalasetty - Is there any way to view VM level compliance via Google Log Explorer apart from above mentioned API??

Comment: As far as I know there is not way to check this from logs.